# ::before pseudo class impacting arrows in react-slick

Tags: react-slick

The previous and next arrows are white when I use the Slider component with minimal settings. This is because slick-theme.css has a `.slick-prev:before` and `.slick-next:before` that sets the color to white, so the arrows are invisible!

Since I have no control over these arrows, I figured I would create custom arrows. I followed the documentation and simply set `color: green` in the style prop. That did nothing, because `.slick-next:before` is really what's being displayed.

How do I get rid of `.slick-next:before` styling?

See [my codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-drake-isfxk?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/custom-arrows) to the documentation on how to use custom arrows.

I wouldn't want to utilize the exact example but just as a reference.

Update:

After reviewing your codesandbox I see you actually tried this but the reason is cause you were applying the default by spreading `...style` in your custom arrow component, you can create a complete custom arrow like this.

```
function SampleNextArrow(props) {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props;
    return (
        <div
            className={className}
            style={{
                height: "20px",
                width: "20px",
                border: "2px solid black",
                transform: "rotate(-45deg)",
                borderWidth: "0px 2px 2px 0px"
            }}
            onClick={onClick}
        />
    );
}
```

I used the simplest way to create an arrow with css border but you can obviously use a background image as well.

Comment: I followed the documentation for custom arrows. It did not work because slick-next:before is what is being displayed, not my custom arrow. I've tried other variations of the custom arrows and I was able to get my arrow to show, but slick-next:before is still on the screen!

Comment: I appreciate the update! However, your update adds content, but does not remove the original slick-next:before element. It's still there. You can't see it because it's white on a white background. I updated my sandbox with your changes. The ::before element is inside the custom arrow. I need it to be removed completely.